Problemas de instalacion de sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit en Jetson Nano
Al tratar de instalar adafruit-circuitpython-servokit en Jetson Nano con:
pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit

me aparece el siguiente error:
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-h0qf28wu/sysv-ipc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-m8sdpr6y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ******************************************************************************
    * Setup can't determine the value of PAGE_SIZE on your system, so it will
    * default to 4096 which may not be correct.
    *
    * Please report this message and your operating system info to the package
    * maintainer listed in the README file.
    ******************************************************************************
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'sysv_ipc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c sysv_ipc_module.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/sysv_ipc_module.o
    sysv_ipc_module.c:32:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-h0qf28wu/sysv-ipc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-m8sdpr6y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-h0qf28wu/sysv-ipc/

La versión de Ubuntu es 18.04 LTS
Actualizacion ya instale
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
y obtengo el mismo error, dejo el codigo completo
~/miPython$ sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
The directory '/home/hexapodo/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/hexapodo/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/0c/3eba1775c6c22474feaee39efa804c719b0b0cc00b2d5524cd7874d92f2c/adafruit_circuitpython_servokit-1.3.17-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0 (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/4e/e8b8e81c345b7e3a3aa184faeb882188e859154aac7fcb7d0e1dda3c9edc/Adafruit_Blinka-8.47.0-py3-none-any.whl (356kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 358kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-register (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/5e/bb4a374ccb7d75f9c8cc22ed9b18f4f568a09f4828446845ae65384f6cc1/adafruit_circuitpython_register-1.9.18-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685 (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/b8/74cb910f6e77cc1e4f0b960b56b31b8b669b8ac9a4495e05007ba437b280/adafruit_circuitpython_pca9685-3.4.15-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-motor (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/3c/6d30e111390b1a0d4b7ea8af44c35bad7efa01411f2003a128bd0774ed6a/adafruit_circuitpython_motor-3.4.13-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: adafruit-circuitpython-typing in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: Adafruit-PlatformDetect>=3.70.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: binho-host-adapter>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: pyftdi>=0.40.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Collecting sysv-ipc>=1.1.0; sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine != "mips" (from Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/d7/5d2f861155e9749f981e6c58f2a482d3ab458bf8c35ae24d4b4d5899ebf9/sysv_ipc-1.1.0.tar.gz (99kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 3.9MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: Adafruit-PureIO>=1.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions~=4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from adafruit-circuitpython-register->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: adafruit-circuitpython-requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from adafruit-circuitpython-typing->Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from binho-host-adapter>=0.1.6->Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: pyusb!=1.2.0,>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pyftdi>=0.40.0->Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Requirement already satisfied: Adafruit-Circuitpython-ConnectionManager in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from adafruit-circuitpython-requests->adafruit-circuitpython-typing->Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0->adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
Installing collected packages: sysv-ipc, Adafruit-Blinka, adafruit-circuitpython-register, adafruit-circuitpython-pca9685, adafruit-circuitpython-motor, adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
Running setup.py install for sysv-ipc ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-fvegukse/sysv-ipc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-elt5b9bs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
******************************************************************************
* Setup can't determine the value of PAGE_SIZE on your system, so it will
* default to 4096 which may not be correct.
*
* Please report this message and your operating system info to the package
* maintainer listed in the README file.
******************************************************************************
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'sysv_ipc' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c sysv_ipc_module.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/sysv_ipc_module.o
sysv_ipc_module.c:32:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"
^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-fvegukse/sysv-ipc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-elt5b9bs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fvegukse/sysv-ipc/

En principio te faltan los archivos de cabecera y librerias estáticas de CPython necesarias para construir paquetes que usan la C-API (escritos en C y que han de ser compilados). Estos vienen con el paquete python-dev, si no lo tienes instalado instalalo con sudo apt-get install python3-dev.

Hola, lo acabo de intentar y me aparece esto hexapodo@hexapodo-desktop:~/miPython$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
[sudo] password for hexapodo:
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
python3-dev ya está en su versión más reciente (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1 no actualizados.
hexapodo@hexapodo-desktop:~/miPython$

al intentar instalar adafruit-circuitpython-servokit me aparece los siguiente The directory '/home/hexapodo/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/hexapodo/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. y el mismo error de arr

Si no estás usando la version del sistema de Python los headers no coincidirán, parece que usas Python 3.8 según la traza de pip, si es así, prueba a instalar python3.8-dev:  sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
